# Pegar valor Radio Button no Foreach- JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Estou tentando pegar o valor do `radio` no `JS` usando `foreach`

```
foreach($produtos as $produto){
 <input type="radio" id="<?php echo trim($produto->CODIGO); ?>" name="plano_ouro" value="<?php echo trim($produto->CODIGO); ?>">
}
```

no `JS` não sei como pegar o que selecionei.

obrigado.

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1911/101 e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/851/101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui esta a solução:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="plano_ouro"]:checked').value;
```

Comment: obrigado @Antony

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do @Antony está correta. Segue o uso com jQuery:

```
$('input[name="plano_ouro"]:checked').val().
```

Comment: Apesar da sua resposta estar correta é desnecessário usar jQuery para algo que o JS puro faz com a mesma simplicidade. Ainda assim dou +1

Comment: @Sergio, apenas para conhecimento. Procuro sempre usar JS puro, mas dependendo da implementação, o jQuery fica mais "legivel" dentro de um código cheio de jQuery. Abraços.